# UITableView - How to update array on + and - click?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

**I was trying to achieve below requirement :**

**Condition :** first row is compulsory with only + button rest of all below are dynamic with
+ and - button.

i.e. i can add from any row and delete any row

e.g. Suppose i have 4 rows, when i click + button from 2nd row there will be one more 
row added after 4th row  and suppose i click on - button from 3rd row that row need to be removed.

**My attempts :**

**First Attempt**

Here is my code snip :

ViewDidLoad

```
 dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
 {
    int value = i;
    [dataArray addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:value]];
 }
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
     [cell.serviceAdd addTarget:self action:@selector(onAddServiceButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [cell.serviceRemove addTarget:self action:@selector(onRemoveButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     cell.serviceAdd.tag = indexPath.row;
     cell.serviceRemove.tag = indexPath.row;
}

    -(void)onAddServiceButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
    {
       //NSLog(@"%ld", (long)sender.tag);
       NSNumber *myNum = dataArray.lastObject; 
       NSNumber *bNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[myNum intValue] + 1];
       NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)dataArray.count);
       [dataArray addObject:bNumber];
       NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)dataArray.count);
       [_serviceListTableview reloadData];
    }

    -(void)onRemoveButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
    {
        NSLog(@"%ld", (long)sender.tag);
        NSInteger mySenderValue = sender.tag;
        NSNumber *myNum = @(mySenderValue);
        NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)dataArray.count);
        [dataArray removeObject:myNum];
        NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)dataArray.count);
        [_serviceListTableview reloadData];
    }
```

**Issue with above code :**

My dataArray having (these are added by clicking on any row of +  button. The list will be in sorted
order only )
        (
            0,
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4
        )

After this i clicked on 2nd row of - Button i.e sender tag is 1
now dataArray
        (
        0,
        2,
        3,
        4
        )

[image]

Now i clicked (price 200) 2nd row again , tag is 1
but that entry not going to be deleted because that is not in array.

**Second Attempt :**

```
    -(void)onAddServiceButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
```

in this method if

```
    NSNumber *myNum = dataArray.lastObject;
```

this line replaced with sender.tag (like implemented in onRemoveButtonClicked )

then entries in dataArray are duplicate as a result when i click - button 2 entries are going to be deleted

**Any suggestion would be a great help for me.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe instead of considering your button tags as direct data in the array you should consider them row indexes because that is what actually they mean. So, you should not use `removeObject:` to update your data model, instead use `removeObjectAtIndex:` by passing the `tag` value.

Comment: Initially my array (0, 6, 7, 8 ) and suppose on tapping onRemoveButtonClicked sender tag is 2 after removing my array (0, 6, 8 ) is it right?

Comment: Yes - this is perfect. You deleted 3rd row (tag = 2) and so third object in your model (which is 7) should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the code in your methods: `onAddServiceButtonClicked` and `onRemoveButtonClicked` with the following code:

```
-(void)onAddServiceButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
   NSInteger count = dataArray.count;
   NSInteger last = count - 1;
   NSInteger newObject = last + 1;

   NSLog(@"Count before adding: %lu", (unsigned long)dataArray.count);
   [dataArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:newObject]];
   NSLog(@"Count after adding: %lu", (unsigned long)dataArray.count);

   [_serviceListTableview reloadData];
}

-(void)onRemoveButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSInteger position = sender.tag;

    NSLog(@"Count before removing row: %lu", (unsigned long)dataArray.count);
    [dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:position];
    NSLog(@"Count after removing row: %lu", (unsigned long)dataArray.count);

    [_serviceListTableview reloadData];
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Using index paths in tags is inherently difficult because as you renumber rows (as a side-effect of deleting rows) the tags stored in cells become incorrect; so you need to refresh the remaining rows.

A better approach than coupling an action from your cell button to your table view controller is to use a delegate pattern from your cell to your tableview controller.

I would suggest something like

In `YourCell.h`

```
@class YourCell;

@protocol YourCellDelegate <NSObject>

@optional -(void) didTapAddInCell:(YourCell *)cell;

@optional -(void) didTapDeleteInCell:(YourCell *)cell;

@end

@interface YourCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak,nonatomic) id<YourCellDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

In `YourCell.m`

```
- (IBAction)addTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didTapAddInCell:)]) {
        [self.delegate didTapAddInCell:self];
    }
}
- (IBAction)deleteTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didTapDeleteInCell:)]) {
        [self.delegate didTapDeleteInCell:self];
    }
}
```

Note.  Set `addTapped` and `deleteTapped` as the action handler for the buttons either in the prototype cell if you are using one or in the cell initialiser

Then in your table view controller, set the delegate when you dequeue the cell and implement the delegate methods (you will also need to change the class definition to indicate that it implements the protocol)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    ...
    cell.delegate=self;
    ...
}

#pragma mark - YourCellDelegate methods

-(void) didTapAddInCell:(YourCell *)cell {
   NSIndexPath *newPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:dataArray.count inSection:0];
   NSNumber *myNum = dataArray.lastObject; 
   NSNumber *bNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[myNum intValue] + 1];
   NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)dataArray.count);
   [dataArray addObject:bNumber];
   NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)dataArray.count);
   [_serviceListTableview addRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

-(void) didTapDeleteInCell:(YourCell *)cell {
    NSIndexPath *deletedPath=[_serviceListTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    if (deletedPath != nil) {
        [dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:deletedPath.row];
        [_serviceListTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[deletedPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
 }
```

Comment: I m totally agree with you but as Abhinav told(below solution) if i perform removeObjectAtIndex in my onRemoveButtonClicked instead of removeObject its working. i did log by checking array values those are correct should i follow/ accpet is answer.?anything wrong in that solution ?

Comment: You can use whatever approach you like. I think my solution is more elegant and avoids the need to reload the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

Fill dataArray with your data, not your index. Looks like you are trying to create some kind of NSDictionary, with index and value. In your case it's not neccessary at all. Use dataArray for data, and element index will be your tag. BTW you can use these functions for one row update:

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:
```